# Htaccess redirect with https and subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

To rewrite http to https and also add "www". But i would like to have also redirect from my subdomains:

```
http://subdomain.mysite.com => https://www.mysite.com
https://subdomain2.mysite.com => https://www.mysite.com
```

etc.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.mysite\.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: its redirecting **http**://subdomain2.mysite.com => https://www.mysite.com
but **https**://subdomain2.mysite.com => https://www.mysite.com not

Comment: @user2075220 are you sure you've cleared your cache? Those rules work fine for me (and on a production site).

Comment: My bad, it works good but i get certificate problem becouse it's not made for subdomains, thanks a lot

Comment: @user2075220 nothing you can do about the certificate, the SSL handshake and certificate exchange happens **before** the request is even transmitted.